# Set the accessibility attributes on UIBarButtonItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, accessibility

I have several UIBarButtonItem objects in Interface Builder, and I cannot find any option to set the accessibility label or hint for these buttons.

How can I set these attributes?

Comment: Is there a way of doing this on a Storyboard in XCode 5?

Answer (score 28):

You can use the "User defined runtime attributes" and specify your accessibility information there:
[image: Runtime attributes]

Comment: Quick correction, for the hint you should use `accessibilityHint`, not `keyPath`

Answer (score 24):

It is not actually enough to just set the `accessibilityLabel` User Defined Runtime Attribute in Interface Builder. You also have to set `isAccessibilityElement` to `true`. This keeps all of the accessibility information within Interface Builder.

[image: IB Screenshot]

Comment: To match other element, the type should be Localized String.

Comment: Can you translate accessibilityLabel set that way?

Answer (score 15):

Okay, so it seems there's no way to do it in Interface Builder, even though you can set accessibility attributes on other UI elements using IB.  So I set a tag on my toolbar and then added this code to my viewWillAppear method:

```
UIToolbar *bottombar = (UIToolbar*)[self viewWithTag:kBottomToolbar];

UIView *view = (UIView*)[bottombar.items objectAtIndex:0];
[view setAccessibilityLabel:NSLocalizedString(@"Add Bookmark", @"")];
[view setAccessibilityHint:NSLocalizedString(@"Add Bookmark", @"")];
```

and so on for each button item...

Not the most elegant, but it works.

Comment: As of iOS 5.0 you can directly set the `accessibilityLabel` property on a `UIBarButtonItem`.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is old but I've just run into a need for this. As of iOS 5.0, you can now easily set the accessibility label of a `UIBarButtonItem` by doing:

```
UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init...;
btn.accessibilityLabel = @"Label";
```

No more hacks.

Answer (score 4):

I got the code above to work with UIBarButtonItems with one extra line:

```
[view setIsAccessibilityElement:YES];
```

Comment: This resolved the issue.  Keep in mind that if a parent view also has this set to YES, then the subviews are ignored.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `IBInspectable` for this so you get some handy options in Interface Builder's side panel.

```
public extension UIBarButtonItem {
  @IBInspectable var accessibilityEnabled: Bool {
    get {
      return isAccessibilityElement
    }
    set {
      isAccessibilityElement = newValue
    }
  }

  @IBInspectable var accessibilityLabelText: String? {
    get {
      return accessibilityLabel
    }
    set {
      accessibilityLabel = newValue
    }
  }
}
```

[image: UIBarButton Accessibility options in Interface Builder]

https://gist.github.com/KaneCheshire/dcce5246c3399072a5200189bfc53fe2

Answer (score 2):

Trying to set accessibility labels manually didn't work for me with UIBarButtonItem images. However, if I set the title manually then the label would work. But it displays the title below the image.

I ended up creating an UIButton and using it as a custom view for the UIBarButtonItem. The only loss being the image masking that UIBarButtonItem performs. Added bonus: accessibility configurable in IB.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 10.2, the *Title* field works well. Here, for example, my button is accessible as "Sort":

[image]